# Naming convention

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Is there a **naming convention** for file classes and properties regarding **Many-To-One / One-To-Many** relations. This might sound like a classic question on naming concention but this is not, it's a question applied to **relations**, let's say in Doctrine for example.

This might be silly but names are quite important, aren't they?

In this case, I have an entity **`GolferProfile`**, an entity **`Category`**, and therefore want an intermediate **`GolferProfile-Category`** entity.

**What class name should I use for the intermediate entity?**

```
GolferProfileCategory OR GolferProfile_Category OR GolferProfile-Category  OR anything else?
```

Same with the property...I have seen people using the first letter of each class, which would be `$gc` in this case. This is pretty much difficult to read, but on the other hand we don't want to work with a long name like `$golferprofile_category`?

Any thoughts on this would help me to understand how to work with names..Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no rule of thumb, but I would recommend sticking to a single practice when it comes to naming conventions for everything: you seem to be using [camelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) already, so why not use it for everything else?

```
GolferProfile
Category
GolferProfileCategory

$golferProfile
$category
$golferProfileCategory
```

Comment: "There is no rule of thumb" No, but there are CS guidelines. And it looks just like that :)

Answer (score 3):

Considering PHP is a C-like language, I would follow its doctrine.

Reference: http://www.psgd.org/paul/docs/cstyle/cstyle04.htm

Comment: Why wouldn't you follow a PHP style guide?

Comment: @Matt Ball : that's the thing, if I use GolferProfile_Category according to [this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html), that would be different from what I inted to do..What would be your recommandation for the classname and property? Many thanks

Comment: That looks pretty dated. I'd definitively not name a variable wllength nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

```
class GolferProfile-Category {}
```

produces [a syntax error](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Px8xfE).

```
GolferProfile_Category {}
```

The underscore will be replace by a directory separator [in PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md).

```
GolferProfileCategory {} // is the winner.
```

> Same with the property...I have seen people using the first letter of each class, which would be $gc in this case. This is pretty much difficult to read, but on the other hand we don't want to work with a long name like $golferprofile_category?

`$gc` is a terrible name. Nobody would know what that means. If you are referring to the variable which is an instance of the class I always go for camelCase.

```
$golferProfileCategory
```

And in my experience most people (at least in PHP) do it this way.

Comment: Many thanks @PeeHaa  +1 for the PSR-0. Didn't know that at all :-)